# fmodex 3d problems

Tags: 3d, distance

I recently am trying to use the fmodex 3D sound library in my OpenGL program, but I'm having some issues.. I've put a speaker in my 3D world, but the sound won't attenuate, no matter how much distance between the source and the camera there is.
Also I have the feeling that when I'm moving the camera, the sound is switching between my 2 speakers (left-right), I don't know if this makes any sense!

Here some code:

```
SoundManager.h

FMOD_SYSTEM *system;
std::vector<Sound*> sounds;
FMOD_VECTOR listenerp;
FMOD_VECTOR velocityp;
FMOD_VECTOR forwardp;
FMOD_VECTOR upp;


//initialisation
FMOD_System_Create(&system);
FMOD_System_Init(system, 32, FMOD_INIT_3D_RIGHTHANDED, NULL);


//update
FMOD_System_Set3DListenerAttributes(system,0, &listenerp, 0, &forwardp, &upp);
FMOD_System_Update(system);




Sound.h
FMOD_SOUND *son;
FMOD_SYSTEM* system;
FMOD_CHANNEL * channel;
FMOD_VECTOR position;
FMOD_VECTOR velocity;

//creating sound
FMOD_RESULT resultat = FMOD_System_CreateSound(system, "data/sounds/forest.wav",     FMOD_3D, 0, &son);

 //playing sound
    FMOD_System_PlaySound(system, FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, son, true, &channel);
    FMOD_Channel_Set3DAttributes(channel,&position, 0);
    FMOD_Channel_SetPaused(channel,false);
```

I'm updating the position of the camera and the source each frame. If someone has an idea i would be very thankful!! :)